# How do I find and replace individual strings in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I am switching my Wordpress-powered website to a new server and changing domain names at the same time, which means I have to find and replace many fields in my MySQL database.

Specifically, I must replace "olddomain.com" with "newdomain.com" whenever they appear in a field in MySQL such as "http://olddomain.com/?p=34".

How can I do a massive find a replace in my MySQL database? I know that the `LIKE` SQL command can find fields with "olddomain.com" in them, but how do I replace specific portions of fields?

Comment: For those interested in migrating WordPress around domains, I've since written a little migration tool to help aid in the process: https://github.com/jeremyharris/wp-tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this search and replace script for this purpose

http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

As the author said raw `replace` is not good in these cases

> When you’re migrating WordPress (or any other platform using
>   serialized PHP strings in the database) between domains, you must use
>   a safe search and replace method that preserves the integrity of the
>   serialized string lengths. A simple of a dump file for
>   localhost to, for example, thenewdomain.com is
>   problematic because the length of the string changes but the indexes
>   for the serialized strings does not. Consequently settings are lost
>   and widgets disappear. Not good.

Referred in [Wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) doc itself.

Answer (score 4):

You can use MySQL's [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `fieldname` = REPLACE(fieldname, 'olddomain', 'newdomain');
```

Another option would be to dump the database and just use a find and replace within your editor of choice.

Comment: It's worth noting that WordPress stores a lot of serialized data (like options for widgets and such) and this method will *break* that data.

Comment: Thank you. Why would it break that data though? Wouldn't it be favorable to replace the old serialized data as well with new data?

Comment: Serialized data relies on string lengths and such (if you look at the data, you'll see something like `s:6:"string"`). Changing string lengths causes PHP to fail when trying to unserialize them. So if the domains are the same lengths, you might get lucky :)

Comment: `Replace` is problematic in such cases because the length of the string changes but the indexes for the serialized strings does not. And that causes problem and settings can be lost.

Comment: At any rate, there's no easy way to move a WordPress site because it hardcodes everything. Generally something will break, I've found. At least knowing what *could* break is helpful.

Comment: I have found this helpful http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you. It will just replace `olddomain.com` with `newdomain.com`. The string on the left and on the right of `olddomain.com` will remain the same.

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, 'olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com')
WHERE columnname LIKE '%olddomain.com%';
```

This is how the function works - `REPLACE(text_string, from_string, to_string)`

Answer (score -1):

Since switching the server means having to dump the database you can just replace olddomain by newdomain in the create script.